# How do I place a stationary wormhole on a planet's surface?

Tags: physics, wormhole, commonwealth-saga

In the [Commonwealth Saga by Peter F. Hamilton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga) (and many other universes) the planets are connected by large wormholes that stay on the surface of the planets so you can travel through with vehicles like trains and cars.

How are these wormholes sustained on one fixed point on the ground of the moving and spinning planets?

Wouldn't a wormhole have a certain movement vector that couldn't cope with a spinning object?

Comment: One may assume that this is a physics problem which Ozzie & Nigel solved when they opened the initial wormhole to Mars.

Comment: This (older) question seems to be asking about how a *real-world wormhole* would work. Those sorts of questions are now off-topic.

Comment: This question is asking about a fictional universe and doesn't deserve to be closed.  The answers are pointing out real world physics isn't the problem the question thinks it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easiest to see how a wormhole can be anchored to a planet by considering so-called "thin shell" wormholes.

The mouth of one of these is the same as its throat.  [In its most symmetrical form, it would manifest as a spherical boundary between two regions of space.  If you were to stick your hand through it, your hand could be thousands of light years away from your shoulder. (One assumes approximate spherical symmetry -- there's at least one hole punched through the thin matter shell through which travelers pass.)]

The matter in the wormhole's throat could be charged, in which case it could be anchored with an electric field.

If this matter is fermionic, it would obey the Pauli Exclusion Principle, and could therefore be anchored by physical constraints composed of fermionic matter -- e.g. an anchoring net.

The wormhole's throat matter, despite being negative, would still be attracted by the planet's gravity.  However, the planet would be repulsed by the wormhole's matter.  If it's a tiny communication wormhole (big enough for, say, a laser beam), this repulsion is insignificant.  It it's a man-sized wormhole, the repulsion would exceed the attraction of any planet whose mass is less than about 1-Jupiter mass.

Despite a great deal of effort by physicists, there is currently no theoretic proof of the non-existence of wormholes.  When quantum theory is considered, negative energy becomes theoretically possible. [Of course, it's also theoretically possible to reverse the rotation of the galaxy.]

It is also possible to engineer a wormhole that has arbitrarily small gravitational effects (these are called "absurdly benign" in the physics literature).   Also, wormholes need not have event horizons.  Although the cost of not having one is negative matter at the wormhole's throat.

Lastly, evidence is not required for rational belief in the existence of a phenomenon.  Belief can be justified by a well tested theory.  For example, there is no evidence for the existence of gravitational waves. But nearly all physicist believe that they exist.  This was much like the widespread belief in the Higgs particle before its discovery in 2012.

Source: The Physics of Stargates -- Parallel Universes, Time Travel, and the Enigma of Wormhole Physics, by Enrico Rodrigo (2010)

Comment: So you say, the "mouth" that is generated by the generator at the "throat's" position at the target will have a mass, that can be positioned on a planets surface? This would explain it a bit: while generating the wormhole you would only have to catch the right position of the target and if there is a gravity field at the target, then the opening there will stay at the position. But wouldn't the target wormhole opening not just fall into the inner of the planet then, consuming parts of it while it falls?

Comment: Just had to say that now gravitational waves have been found...wormholes to be next ? ;)

Answer (score 9):

There are all sorts of problems with wormholes:

1. There is no evidence they exist.
2. Schwarzchild wormholes are surrounded by an event horizon (essentially making them look like black holes from the outside), which would completely destroy the surroundings whether or not the object was spinning
3. Traversable (Lorentzian) wormholes also have very strong distortions in spacetime with all sorts of nasty consequences for matter nearby.

So not only would they have trouble staying fixed to the ground, they'd tend to shred everything near the planet they were on (possibly including the whole planet).

Since this is not such a good plot device for most stories, one imagines that these sorts of issues are somehow circumvented.  If you can do that, getting it to stick to the surface of the planet instead of orbiting around it at surface elevation (for example) doesn't seem like an insurmountable additional task.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) for more information, or [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1563966530) (Amazon.com--text not available online AFIAK) for the mathematical physics of "real" wormholes.

Comment: This. It's called science *fiction*.

Comment: @evilsoup - People like science fiction of varying degrees of hardness.  My point is that if you want it so hard that you have to worry about the angular velocity of the planet, there are other much bigger things to worry about.

Comment: Are Lorentzian and Schwarzschild wormholes not the same thing, both other names for Einstein–Rosen bridges? Traversable wormholes such as the Morris–Thorne wormhole are Lorentzian/Schwarzchild/Einstein-Rosen bridges where the throat of the worm hole are held open by exotic matter?

Answer (score -2):

If the wormhole is connected by quantum entanglement the movement of the planets should not matter.

I say this because if mere movement broke entanglement it would never be observed because everything is always moving. In fact the point of entanglement is spooky action at a distance - instant effect not limited by the speed of light. (Like if measuring one of a pair of photons as a particle it will instantly force the other one to act like a particle too no matter how far away in a spooky cosmic conspiracy.)

The theory ER = EPR is the theory promoted by Leonard Susskind that two early physics theories are in fact the same thing.  The Einstein - Rosen bridge "wormhole" and the Einstein, Rosen, Podolsky entanglement theory.

Basically it's derived from if you get a wormhole from entanglement of black holes it's still a wormhole at all quantum entanglements.  Connection by a wormhole explains the instant effects of entanglement.

See: Wormholes Untangle a Black Hole Paradox

https://www.quantamagazine.org/wormhole-entanglement-and-the-firewall-paradox-20150424/

Comment: The question was about how to keep them flying off (since it was about SF where they were supposed to be part of a reliable transportation network), not saying anything about movement breaking the connection between the two ends of the wormhole if they *did* fly off.

Comment: @Hypnosifl 1. All the other answers are about physics. 2. The question is about movement.  3. Implicitly whatever in-universe gadget is forming the wormhole is what is doing the entanglement.  (For example a stargate)

Comment: All the other answers are about the physics of keeping them in one place, which is relevant to the question, not about the physics of whether the connection between the two ends of the wormhole would disappear if they failed to keep them in place, which isn't what was being asked about. I also don't see how it's relevant that the device that forms them initially is creating the connection, unless you think the device is still active and holding them in place somehow *after* they have already formed.

Comment: @Hypnosifl 1. I am demonstrating that the wormhole is attached to the gate.  2. Moving the gate doesn't matter. (Planet rotating etc.) 3. Pointing out the gate is bolted to the floor is not that interesting.

Comment: *How* are you demonstrating the wormhole is attached to the gate? Is the stuff about ER=EPR supposed to be related to this? If so, the ER=EPR conjecture says nothing about how large wormholes could be created (it deals only with the idea that individual particles are tiny wormholes in some sense), nor anything about artificial means needed to maintain the connection between two ends of a wormhole.

Comment: @Hypnosifl you are wrong ER=EPR is about entangled black holes (meaning big scifi wormholes) as much as it is about photons. There are plenty of Susskind lectures on the internet. Pointing out how say a gate in any fictional property stays on doesn't really  matter if the question (now closed - so I'm done with you) is fundamentally how does a gate work on a rotating planet. And fundamentally the answer remains according to physics moving doesn't break entanglement = aka wormholes.

Comment: ER=EPR is about entangled particle pairs, but was thought up as an attempt to solve certain difficulties about examples where one particle crosses the event horizon of a black hole and the other does not. In any case, ER=EPR has nothing to do with artificial "gates" that create or maintain wormholes (small or large), again the idea is supposed to be that these wormholes are naturally-occurring.